# PHP contact form goes to a blank page

Tags: php, contact-form

My beloved PHP contact form goes to a blank page, email is not going through either. I've added an echo function at the end to see if it goes through the entire code. That worked, the echoed line was showing up. Quite a newbie in PHP, so please don't bite my head off. 
This is the project I'm working on: http://www.designbynoemi.co.uk.

Any direction would be highly appreciated.

And here is my code:

```
    <?php
/*
* Contact Form Class
*/

error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');

$admin_email = 'contact@designbynoemi.co.uk'; // Your Email
$message_min_length = 5; // Min Message Length


class Contact_Form{
    function __construct($details, $email_admin, $message_min_length){

        $this->name = stripslashes($details['name']);
        $this->email = trim($details['email']);
        $this->subject = 'Contact from Your Website'; // Subject 
        $this->message = stripslashes($details['message']);

        $this->email_admin = $email_admin;
        $this->message_min_length = $message_min_length;

        $this->response_status = 1;
        $this->response_html = '';
    }


    private function validateEmail(){
        $regex = '/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i';

        if($this->email == '') { 
            return false;
        } else {
            $string = preg_replace($regex, '', $this->email);
        }

        return empty($string) ? true : false;
    }


    private function validateFields(){
        // Check name
        if(!$this->name)
        {
            $this->response_html .= '<p>Please enter your name</p>';
            $this->response_status = 0;
        }

        // Check email
        if(!$this->email)
        {
            $this->response_html .= '<p>Please enter an e-mail address</p>';
            $this->response_status = 0;
        }

        // Check valid email
        if($this->email && !$this->validateEmail())
        {
            $this->response_html .= '<p>Please enter a valid e-mail address</p>';
            $this->response_status = 0;
        }

        // Check message length
        if(!$this->message || strlen($this->message) < $this->message_min_length)
        {
            $this->response_html .= '<p>Please enter your message. It should have at least '.$this->message_min_length.' characters</p>';
            $this->response_status = 0;
        }
    }


    private function sendEmail(){
        $mail = mail($this->email_admin, $this->subject, $this->message,
             "From: ".$this->name." <".$this->email.">\r\n"
            ."Reply-To: ".$this->email."\r\n"
        ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());

        if($mail)
        {
            $this->response_status = 1;
            $this->response_html = '<p>Thank You!</p>';
        }
    }


    function sendRequest(){
        $this->validateFields();
        if($this->response_status)
        {
            $this->sendEmail();
        }

        $response = array();
        $response['status'] = $this->response_status;   
        $response['html'] = $this->response_html;

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}


$contact_form = new Contact_Form($_POST, $admin_email, $message_min_length);
$contact_form->sendRequest();

echo "Hello world!"; 

?>
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: white screen of death: error checking\display are off, turn them on to see the error. at the top of your php page add: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); ini_set('html_errors', 0); error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: Thanks Jay, looking better now. :)

Comment: alright, it's looking better now. I'm getting: {"status":1,"html":"<p>Thank You!<\/p>"}, but no email coming through. Any suggestion?

Comment: It could have been lost by your SMTP server, or it is lagging on the target email server, or you just got sent to spam. Who knows. All mail() return tells you is that the function successfully passed the hot potato to the next service.

Comment: That's a great help. At least the function successfully passed. That was my main concern.